# Performance of == vs Equals in generic C# class

Tags: c#, performance, generics, operators

For some reason C# does not allow == operator use in generic classes like here:

```
class Mine<T> where T : struct
{
    T val;
    public T Value 
    { 
        set 
        { 
            if (val == value) // Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type T and T happens here
            {
                // .. do something ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace == with val.Equals(value) I have code that works as expected but if I look at bytecode it looks much more complicated. 
A very simple test comparing int variables in the loop using == and Equals() showed that Equals() version was two times slower than "==" version.

I wonder if there is a way to compare primitive value types in generic classes that would be as fast as == operator. 
Any ideas welcome.

**Edit:**
I got lost between timers. Performance difference is not as dramatic. Here are my latest results:

```
== operator                            1974380 ticks
Equals()                               1976358 ticks
== operator in another static function 1974604 ticks
EqualityComparer<int>.Default...      32486695 ticks
```

In short: Equals() is good enough.

Comment: Can you add the `IEquatable<T>` constraint to the class?

Comment: Same situation with IEquatable<T>.  Operator "==" cannot be applied.

Comment: Sure. The interface above has a method `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)`. Please see my answer below.

Comment: "if I look at bytecode it looks much more complicated" more complicated than what? The code with `==` doesn't compile, so it produces no IL ;)

Comment: btw, beware of `val.Equals(value)`: it will throw if `val` is null. You can use the static `Object.Equals(val, value)` method instead, which takes care of that case.

Comment: No the problem is that code that compares two ints using == is twice as fast as code using Equals() but I have to use Equals() in generic class thus my generic class is twice as slow when comparing.

Comment: @OptionalOption that's because int comparison has its own IL opcode; it can be executed directly by the runtime, no method call is necessary. But it only works for some types, so it can't be used in a generic method.

Comment: So I wanted to know if there is some solution to force compiler to emit fast IL code in my generic class. If it is not possible then I can always create a bunch of non-generic classes. Not loving such solution but in this case performance is very important.

Comment: Twice as fast is a relative term. Performance should have absolute goals, I wouldn't care less if twice as slow still meets my goals. Quite honestly you must have some very fine tuned software in your hands if your performance bottleneck is pending upon using `int == int` instead of `int.Equals(int)`.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thats kind of hard when `T` is constrained to `struct`.

Comment: @InBetween good point, I hadn't noticed the constraint ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason being that `==` defaults to reference equality and that makes no sense for value types, the answer will always be `false`. Because there is no language mechanism to constrain generic types based upon static methods, the compiler simply disallows this as it can't verify that `T` really has an overloaded `==` operator.

On the other hand if you constraint `T` to `class` it will compile just fine because reference equality does make sense for reference types.

The solution is of course `IEquatable<T>`; in any sanely implemented struct `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T t)` will give you value equality semantics and `==` should behave consistently.

And answering your question, no there is not. If you really need the speed of `int == int` you will need to implement a non generic specialized class.

Answer (score 5):

If you are allowed to add the `IEquatable<T>` constraint to the class, then you can use the `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)` method declared in that interface:

```
class Mine<T> where T : struct, IEquatable<T>
{
    T val;
    public T Value
    {
        set
        {
            if (val.Equals(value)) // 
            {
                // .. do something ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this Equals() somehow different from Equals() that I call for 2 ints i and j  like this i.Equals(j)?

Comment: @OptionalOption Yes. The only `Equals` method you can use without `IEquatable<T>` is `object.Equals(object)` which leads to boxing of your integers.

Comment: Another option to avoid boxing is to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(val, value)`

Comment: Tried this one for int and performance is atrocious. It is 15 times slower than == and 7 times slower than Equals()

Comment: @OptionalOption I don't know how you check the performance. Here is my check: [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZoHRyj).

Comment: Thank you man, my timers were off ====:O  == beats Equals() by 0.1 percent.

Comment: @OptionalOption [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Careful when `val == null`.

Comment: @AlexReinking `val` cannot be `null` since it's a `struct`.